# I there any way to write any code to get member for telegram channel?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I was reading any answer for this question but no one knows if there any code for any language for get telegram member for channel.if any one knows how it work please answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Telegram CLI for this purpose.
also your account need to be admin of that channel

Comment: I use it and it not add member to channel .